# Отображение и анимация изображений как объектов в С++

Tags: c++, изображения, анимация, разработка-игр

---

Здравствуйте, у меня есть задание реализовать игру. И Вот в примере экзешника есть кружки, изображение в центре, курсор кастомной картинкой сделан(кружком), ну и на ПКМ могу стрельнуть тоже пикчей. Вопрос в том, как в принципе можно реализовать поле, на котором можно размещать картинки, обозначать их поведение и вообще контролировать их как-то.

---

**P.S.** НЕ прошу какого-то конкретного решения, прошу направить меня на те темы которые нужно гуглить и понимать.
**P.S.S** Скрин примера ниже:)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шото непонятно в чём проблема. Как кружки задать так, чтобы можно было узнать пересекаются ли они с курсором? Ну так центром и радиусом, например

Comment: @dIm0n не понятно как эти кружки и вообще всё отрисовать вот так, это если кратко)

Comment: Используйте любую библиотеку, умеющую рисовать графические примитивы. Кружки почти любая умеет: SFML, SDL, WinAPI в конце концов :)

Comment: Qt(QGraphicsScene) или Borland Builder